# ASP.NET: How can I "display: none" ASP validators when not required?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following asp code:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewPassword" TextMode="Password" Placeholder="New Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorNewPassword"
      runat="server" ErrorMessage="New Password required" ControlToValidate="txtNewPassword" ForeColor="Red">
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
      ErrorMessage="Password must be at least 6 characters long" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtNewPassword"
      ValidationExpression="[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,}"/>
```

The thing is that they are hidden in visibiliy and not in display when not required, but that is a problem because they take space nonetheless.

Comment: Use this type="hidden" Or-else use Style="display: none"

Comment: Add `Display="Dynamic"` to the validator.

Comment: @VDWWD Perfect! Thank you so much, that fixed it.